# Is there an AS3 Minify? How do I minify actionscript3?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, minify

I've found several javascript minify tools however they do something weird with open and close braces, even though ActionScript is based on ECMAScript it doesn't seem to work. Wondering if anyone knows of an actionscript3 minifier that I could use. Anyone?

Answer (score 6):

There is no need to minify AS3.  AS3 gets compiled to bytecode which is then wrapped in a gzip compressed swf.

Comment: Why are flash decompilers able to extract so much information out, including variable names and comments? Seems like there's plenty of room for minification.

Comment: @Jay Paroline, Minification is meant to reduce space which isn't needed since swf is a compressed format.  If you want to hide from decompilers than you wand an obfuscator.

Comment: Doesn't minification also involve stripping comments and replacing vars with smaller names? Does compression really make the space difference negligible?

Comment: @Jay Paroline, compilation strips comments. There's even more to it than compression though.  AS3 code is compiled to bytecode which means the only strings left are your variable names and the literals.  All code elements are converted to binary representations.  Minification does nothing for code elements except remove whitespace.  Then AS3 is compressed on top of that.

Comment: I would love to have one as well. I understand it's not needed but when you are obliged to give out some of your coding to aholes, it's nice to know they will have a hard time working with it.

Comment: @Eric, you want an obfuscator, not a minimizer. An obfuscator makes reading decompiled code more difficult.

Comment: @Samuel, no i am not talking about compiled code, but source code.

Comment: @Eric, if you have a contract with a client that requires giving away your code, you should give away your original code.  Giving them a minimized version would be a totally horrible move.  However, that at least makes some sense, even though I still disagree.

Comment: @SamuelNeff, i can feel you haven't made a lot of business. Live and learn. Also source code giving is something to negotiate, it all depends on the terms of the contract, you don't have to give it away if it wasn't sold. Professional like me work with custom homemade frameworks which represent a lot more time and investment than some shitty project for shitty people, and there is noway i'm giving out my framework for free :) Good luck with your morals man lol this is a shark world.

Comment: @Eric, you're right, source code is something you negotiate, but if you negotiate that they get the source code, they should get the real source code, not a version you intentionally crapped up.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to minify action script code. but just found this tool , that does what you want. http://codebeautify.org/actionscript

Answer (score 0):

I used a tool named irrfuscator, it has limitations because is not so smart so I could not used it on Flex projects that link to other projects (i split my code in projects) and you need to make sure you don't use dynamic features, also make sure to test the result, so for simple projects it works, for complex code or direct sqf obfuscator I don't recomend obfuscation because it is hard